# armv7s executable size increase

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, armv7

With XCode4.5 and armv7+armv7s arch, the executable size increased from 3MB to 7MB. Rebuild with armv7 only, the binary size is back to 3MB.

Does anyone see the same increase? Is this an expected result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were previously building for one arch, now you are building for two; this means that roughly twice as much code is generated, so a 2x increase in binary size shouldn't be a surprise.